# How to add a Login drop down on navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, if you go to: **https://www.waveapps.com/** and click on 'Sign in' you'll get a nice drop down to sign in with.

How might I create something like this? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, and rather than re-directing the users to a sign-in page I'd like to have a similar drop down to allow users to sign-in. It's simply more appealing.

How might I do this?

Any help would be way cool!!

Cheers!

Comment: Please check http://www.bootply.com/60886

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap's popover or Modal features.

[See docs here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Collapsable nav bar --> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

            <!-- Your site name for the upper left corner of the site --> <a class="brand">My Site</a>

            <!-- Start of the nav bar content -->
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <!-- Other nav bar content -->... ...
                <!-- The drop down menu -->
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                            <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" />
                                <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" />
                                <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                                <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    // Setup drop down menu
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

    // Fix input element click problem
    $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hk32N/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply position a div above the viewable window, for example if it is 200px high, give it a css top value of -80px so the bottom of it is just at the top of your screen, then when hovered animate the div into view.

```
#loginbox {
top:-80px;
width:600px;
height:100px;
}
```

and

```
$('#loginbox').hover(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({'top', '0px'}, 1000
}, function() {
$(this).stop().animate({'top', '-80px'},750
});
```